# Extracting images from webpage and comparing

Tags: java, parsing

I am developing a java project where i am trying to extract images from two given url's and compare them one by one. After comparing i am in need of producing an output that, whether all images match one another or not. So how to write such a java program. If there is a way to do the same with Html parsers like HTMLParser (i am using it in my project) kindly tell me how to do it with HTMLParser.

Answer (score 0):

We can only help you if you have tried something. A simple google search gave me this link http://chasethedevil.blogspot.de/2006/05/java-html-parsing-example-with.html. This describes how to parse a hyperlink tag. You can simply change it to use the img src tag and then extract the filename from the tag and do your comparison.

Comment: I am not sure how he wants to implement it. As far as I think, the name doesnt matter in file comparison tools.